# Remove patterns in a tab file

Tags: awk, sed

`enter code here`Hi everyone
I have a data frame such as :

I have a file such as:

```
scaffold_1_1    X   2   2
scaffold_24_0   X   9   2
scaffold_15 X   2   2
IDBA_scaffold_30_1  X   2   317
scf7180005161000_2  X   1   2
```

And the idea is simply to remove the last number part of all names in the first
but there are 3 types of scaffolds_names:

```
scaffold_number0_number1
scaffold_number0
IDBA_scaffold_number0_number1
scfXXX_number1
```

and the idea is to remove all the number_1, here is the result I should get in this example:

```
scaffold_1  X   2   2
scaffold_24 X   9   2
scaffold_15 X   2   2
IDBA_scaffold_30    X   2   317
scf7180005161000    X   1   2
```

Have you an idea to deal with that?

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Perl,

```
perl -pe ' s/(^\S+)_\d\b/$1/g '
```

with your inputs

```
$ cat bean.txt
scaffold_1_1    X   2   2
scaffold_24_0   X   9   2
scaffold_15 X   2   2
IDBA_scaffold_30_1  X   2   317
scf7180005161000_2  X   1   2
$ perl -pe ' s/(^\S+)_\d\b/$1/g ' bean.txt
scaffold_1    X   2   2
scaffold_24   X   9   2
scaffold_15 X   2   2
IDBA_scaffold_30  X   2   317
scf7180005161000  X   1   2
$
```

Thanks @anubhava for catching one of the edge cases and helping to fix it.

```
$ cat bean2.txt
scaffold_1_1    X   2   2
scaffold_24_0   X   9   2
scaffold_15 X   2   2
IDBA_scaffold_30_1  X   2   317
scaffold_1_15     X   2   2  # => this was not fixed in first answer
$ perl -pe 's/^(?!scaffold_\d+\b)(\S+)_\d+\b/$1/g' bean2.txt
scaffold_1    X   2   2
scaffold_24   X   9   2
scaffold_15 X   2   2
IDBA_scaffold_30  X   2   317
scaffold_1     X   2   2
$
```

Comment: @anubhava sir, you are right.. I just tried ````perl -pe ' s/(^.+?)(_\d+)?_\d+\b/$2?"$1$2":$&/ge '````, pls review.. if ok, I'll add to the answer

Comment: That may work for OP's data but new regex might be error prone. I think it would be better to use negative lookahead e.g. `perl -pe 's/^(?!scaffold_\d+\b)(\S+)_\d+\b/$1/g' file`

Comment: @anubhava sir, I need your help in reviewing my regex solution to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54972535/delete-duplicate-lines-only-if-they-match-a-pattern/54985530#54985530 please review when you get time

Answer (score 2):

***1st Solution:*** Could you please try following.(in case someone simply want to substitute last `_` and following digits then only following may help.

```
awk '{sub(/_[0-9]+$/,"",$1)} 1'  Input_file
```

***2nd solution:***

In case you want to check if there should be more than 2 `_` values in 1st field which is starting from string `sacffold` then try following.

```
awk '(/scaffold/ && num=split($1,a,"_")>2) || /scf/{sub(/_[0-9]+$/,"",$1)} 1' Input_file
```

Output will be as follow.

```
scaffold_1 X 2 2
scaffold_24 X 9 2
scaffold_15 X   2   2
IDBA_scaffold_30 X 2 317
scf7180005161000 X 1 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but as you can see, the _15 part has been removed and it has to be kept for this one..

Comment: @bean, please try my 2nd solution and let me know then?

Comment: Now there is still the _2 after scf7180005161000_2

Comment: Please check my 2nd solution now. It is edited, let me know then.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `awk` variant:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $1 ~ /^scf[0-9]+_[0-9]+$/ || split($1, a, "_") > 2 {
sub(/_[0-9]+$/, "", $1) } 1' file
```

```
scaffold_1  X   2   2
scaffold_24 X   9   2
scaffold_15 X   2   2
IDBA_scaffold_30    X   2   317
scf7180005161000    X   1   2
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Thanks, ++ for your solution. I think OP wants `scf7180005161000` in output instead of `scf7180005161000_2`

Answer (score 0):

Using any sed that supports `-E` for EREs, e.g. GNU or OSX/BSD seds:

```
$ sed -E 's/((_|scf)[0-9]+)_[0-9]+/\1/' file
scaffold_1    X   2   2
scaffold_24   X   9   2
scaffold_15 X   2   2
IDBA_scaffold_30  X   2   317
scf7180005161000  X   1   2
```